# Django Passkeys and NextJs

Tags: django, rest, authentication, next.js, passkey

I would like to create an app based on Django and NextJS 13 that uses an authentication system using Passkeys. I have seen that there is a django package for passkeys but it seems not to work properly, or at least following the documentation it is not explained correctly with implement the system if you use an external framework like NextJS.

I am therefore looking for a solution that will allow me to use passkeys as my login system.

Comment: I recommend SimpleWebAuthn (simplewebauthn.dev)

Comment: Where can I find documentation for django?